# Remove all unused rows and columns from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a simple way to remove all unused  columns and rows form a Sheet using GAS?

If I use `sheet.getLastColumn` it only grabs columns with data, which makes sense but I think the Sheet looks cleaner if unused columns and rows are removed.

I can remove them using `sheet.deleteRows(LastRow, x)` where x would be the number  of rows to remove after the last row with data, but that number isn't constant each time the script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getMaxRows() and getMaxColumns() to get the total size of the sheet.

So then it's just a matter of using getLastRow() / getLastColumn() values to figure out the parameters for deleteRows() and/or deleteColumns()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxColumns()

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that. My apologies. Thank you!